# ** reference to a Variable

Tags: python

I've that variable

```
    data = {
        'username' : self.username,
        'attributes' : self._get_attrs(),
        }
```

What does it mean when I reference it like  **data ?

Comment: @Rogalski: I initially also thought this was a duplicate, but the other question is only about stars *in parameters*.

Answer (score 1):

`**` in `**data` is a dictionary unpacking operator in Python. See [What is the name of `**` in python?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131403/1985)

From `help('CALLS')`:

> If the syntax "**expression" appears in the function call,
>   "expression" must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are
>   treated as additional keyword arguments.  In the case of a keyword
>   appearing in both "expression" and as an explicit keyword argument, a
>   "TypeError" exception is raised.

See [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/4279).

There is also [PEP: 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> {**{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, **{'a': 3, 'c': 4}}
{'b': 2, 'a': 3, 'c': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `**` expands your dictionary. Example:

```
def func(username=None, attributes=None):
    print(username)

data = {
    'username'   : "Bob",
    'attributes' : {},
}

func(**data)
# results in "Bob"
```

It can also be used to collect keyword arguments (kwargs), as seen in [this question about *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters).

Comment: Also, in Python 3.5+, [it can be used more generally to construct `dict`s from other mappings.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), e.g. combining two `dict`s to make a new third `dict` with `combined = {**dict1, **dict2}`.